# Prove a property of a function with a decEq in it

Tags: idris

It's easy to prove

```
f : Nat -> Nat

proveMe : (x : Nat) -> Maybe Nat
proveMe x = if (f x) == 0 then Just 42 else Nothing

theProof : (x : Nat) -> (f x = Z) -> (Just 42 = proveMe x)
theProof x prf = rewrite prf in Refl
```

But what if the calculation of `Just 42` requires the proof that `f x = 0`?

```
proveMe2 : (x : Nat) -> Maybe Nat
proveMe2 x with (decEq (f x) Z)
    | Yes prf = Just 42
    | No _ = Nothing

theProof2 : (x : Nat) -> (f x = Z) -> (Just 42 = proveMe2 x)
theProof2 x prf = ?howToFillThis
```

How can I prove it now?

I tried to "follow the structure of the `with` clause", but when doing so I would have to convince idris that the contra-case is impossible:

```
theProof3 : (x : Nat) -> (f x = Z) -> (Just 42 = proveMe2 x)
theProof3 x prf with (decEq (f x) Z)
    | Yes prf2 = Refl
    | No contra impossible -- "...is a valid case"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had completely forgotten about `void : Void -> a`. Using *Ex falso quodlibet* the proof is simply

```
theProof3 : (x : Nat) -> (f x = Z) -> (Just 42 = proveMe2 x)
theProof3 x prf with (decEq (f x) Z)
    | Yes prf2 = Refl
    | No contra = void $ contra prf
```